# Condensing multiCapabilities information

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

```
  multiCapabilities: [
{
    shardTestFiles: true,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 1,
    sequential: true,
    specs: ['test-cases/welcome-page/spec.js']
},
{
    shardTestFiles: true,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 1,
    sequential: true,
    specs: ['test-cases/dashboard/spec.js']
}  ]
```

**Note:** I am running these tests sequentially, not in parallel by using `maxSessions: 1,` as a result, there will be roughly 30 different spec.js files in this multiCapabilities.

Therefore this would imply 120 unnecessary lines of code. **Is there a way I can condense this into an area I can reference?** I tried taking shardTestFiles - > sequential lines to the top of the conf.js file, but it seems there must be some sort of call inside multiCapabilities.

Comment: More specifically: I want to remove shardTestFiles, 'browserName', maxInstances, and sequential for each part of multiCapabilities since the information will be constant across each spec file.